# Eigenvalues of Hessian Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix

I have been trying to compute the eigenvalues of the following hessian matrix but have been unable to thus far:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
2a & c & 0\\
c & 2b & d \\
0 & d & 2b \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

I have gotten to the stage where:

$ \det(H-\lambda I) = (2a-\lambda )(2b-\lambda )^2 - (2a-\lambda )(d)^2 - (2b-\lambda )(c)^2 $

I can't seem to solve for $ \lambda_i $, is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Concerning a Hessian, one is usually not interested in the eigenvalues itself but in their signs.  Determine the signs would be simpler.